# Is the ExpoFileSystem.documentDirectory similar to the RNFetchBlob dirs?

Tags: react-native, expo, rn-fetch-blob, expo-file-system

I'm part of a team that is developing a new application based on an older one. This old application saves data in a local sqlite database and according to the team leaders, it is important that this old database is reused in our application.

The problem is: the old application uses RNFetchBlob and our new application uses Expo and all its dependencies (FileSystem).

The old database was at:

let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
path: (Platform.OS=='ios' ? dirs.LibraryDir : dirs.DocumentDir) + "/db.sqlite"

The question is: is there a way to reopen the old database using FileSystem + sqlite from expo?

I tried to access the archives but it seems like its not accessed. I want to access the db.sqlite in the new application that uses other file api (Expo File system) than the old one (RNFetchBlob).